# Problem with Oracle Rollback Segment Session

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am facing a problem in **Oracle**, which after performing a procedure that performs `INSERT` or `UPDATE` with a millions amount of record in a table, not the next procedure "*sees*" the data in the table already inserted. My procedure is scheduled to perform commit 100 thousand lines. I also use *cursors* with *bulk collection*.

I suspect the problem may be due to the area **Rollback** **segment** of the *Session* of **Oracle**, anyone know if there is any **DML** command to clear the area or give a flush on Rollback segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're using multiple sessions and the other session cannot "see" the work performed because it is currently uncommitted.

The default Oracle transaction [Isolation Level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) is Read Committed. This means that a  session will not be able to see the work a given session has done until it has explicitly committed the transaction.

The Oracle Server Concepts Guide [explains this in detail](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/consist.htm#CNCPT020).

Comment: But it is in the same session. The second procedure to be performed does not see the newly inserted data, however, they are there.

Comment: Does it not "see" all of the data, or just some of the data? If your session cannot "see" ANY of the data (even after commit) then you're facing a different issue than if your session cannot "see" some of the data, but can see some of it.